# How to suppress warning about backslashed character being treated as a literal character?

Tags: regex, perl

In my code I make a string that kinda resembles an IP address, using the `random_regex` function from String::Random

```
  $ip = random_regex('\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}');
```

This is inside of a loop and whenever it hits this line, Perl outputs:

```
'\.' being treated as literal '.' at ./test_data.pl line 67
'\.' being treated as literal '.' at ./test_data.pl line 67
'\.' being treated as literal '.' at ./test_data.pl line 67
```

How do I ignore or suppress this warning? Or perhaps modify the regex to avoid it altogether?

Comment: FWIW using double quotes made it go away for me. Perl 5.14.2 on Ubuntu 12.10

Answer (score 4):

I can't fathom why `random_regex` is issuing this warning. It makes no sense to issue it for non-word chars, much less `.`.

Furthermore, it provides no mechanism for disabling it, so you'll need to hook in.

```
my $ip = do {
   local $SIG{__WARN__} = sub {
      return if $_[0] =~ /^'\\(\W)' being treated as literal '\1'/;
      print(STDERR $_[0]);
   };

   random_regex('\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}')
};
```